Why are LineChart lines plotting above the correct grid line?
I have a LineChart where axisLeft.axisMinimum = -0.5f a set of points that are y=[0,0,3,0,0]. For some reason, the line starts plotting above the 0 grid line even though the value is 0. Why would a -0.5f shift the whole graph like this and mess up the grid line?

I originally set axisMinimum = -0.5 because I wanted the full line to show when the line was calculated to be on the 0 gridline. It would normally get cut off but I found that setting it to -0.5, allowed the full line to show. example with different data:

current code:
val dataPoints = listOf(
    Entry(1f, 2f),
    Entry(2f, 0f),
    Entry(2.5f, 0f),
    Entry(2.7f, 0f),
    Entry(3f, 4f),
    Entry(4f, 5f)
)
val chartdata = LineData(
    LineDataSet(
        dataPoints,
        "Label",
    )
)
AndroidView(
    modifier = modifier,
    factory = { context ->
        LineChart(context).apply {
            setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor)
            setPinchZoom(false)
            setTouchEnabled(false)
            setScaleEnabled(false)
            setDrawBorders(false)
            setMaxVisibleValueCount(0)
            isHighlightPerDragEnabled = false
            isHighlightPerTapEnabled = false
            description.isEnabled = false
            isDragEnabled = false
            xAxis.apply {
                setDrawGridLines(false)
                setLabelCount(3, true)
                setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true)
                position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
                textSize = 12.sp.value
                textColor = axisLeftTextColor
                isGranularityEnabled = true
                granularity = maxXSize.div(2)
                yOffset = 20f
                axisMinimum = -0.5f
                axisMaximum = maxXSize
                axisLineColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
                valueFormatter =
                    object : ValueFormatter() {
                        override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float) =
                            when (value) {
                                0f -> xAxisRange.axisLabel?.start
                                maxXSize.div(2) -> xAxisRange.axisLabel?.middle
                                else -> xAxisRange.axisLabel?.end
                            } ?: ""
                    }
            }
            axisLeft.apply {
                setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART)
                setDrawGridLines(true)
                setLabelCount(3, true)
                textSize = 12.sp.value
                textColor = axisLeftTextColor
                isGranularityEnabled = true
                granularity = maxYSize.div(2)
                axisMinimum = -0.3f
                axisMaximum = maxYSize + 0.05f
                xOffset = 16f
                axisLineColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
                gridColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
                valueFormatter =
                    object : ValueFormatter() {
                        override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float) =
                            getFormattedYAxisValue(value.toLong())
                    }
            }
            axisRight.apply {
                axisLineColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
                textColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
                isGranularityEnabled = true
                granularity = maxYSize.div(4)
                axisMinimum = -0.3f
                axisMaximum = maxYSize + 0.05f
                gridColor = gridLineColor
                x = -5f
                setLabelCount(5, true)
            }
            data =
                chartdata.apply {
                    dataSets.mapNotNull {
                        (it as? LineDataSet)?.apply {
                            setDrawCircles(false)
                            setDrawCircleHole(false)
                            setDrawValues(false)
                            cubicIntensity = 0.15f
                            mode = LineDataSet.Mode.HORIZONTAL_BEZIER
                            lineWidth = 3.dp.value
                            color = pointLineColor
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    },
    update = { chart ->
        chart.apply {
            legend.isEnabled = false
            xAxis.apply {
                granularity = maxXSize.div(2)
                axisMaximum = maxXSize
            }
            axisLeft.apply {
                granularity = maxYSize.div(2)
                axisMaximum = maxYSize + 0.05f
            }
            axisRight.apply {
                granularity = maxYSize.div(4)
                axisMaximum = maxYSize + 0.05f
            }
            data =
                chartdata.apply {
                    dataSets.mapNotNull {
                        (it as? LineDataSet)?.apply {
                            setDrawCircles(false)
                            setDrawCircleHole(false)
                            setDrawValues(false)
                            cubicIntensity = 0.15f
                            mode = LineDataSet.Mode.HORIZONTAL_BEZIER
                            lineWidth = 3.dp.value
                            color = pointLineColor
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
        chart.invalidate()
    },
)

I was expecting the line to be plotted on the current y-axis grid line and the minimum to only account for slightly negative values, not shift the whole graph up.

It seems like when you force label count with setLabelCount(5, true) it also forces the first grid line to appear at the very bottom (below 0). The label still shows 0 because it is converted to a fixed point value.
Try not to force label count, i.e. replace setLabelCount(5, true) with setLabelCount(5, false)
